# Not Reading Database Even Without Hash

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to figure out why this script runs to "login faileda" and quits. Technically I know why(no match,but there is a match). Initially I thought maybe it was issue with password hash, but I've removed that to test for the password. I've tried to manually place the password and username within the database to get a match. Is there any other reason that this could not be working? These are the scripts I'm running.

**Signin.php**

```
<?php
include_once("includes/check_login_status.php");
// If user is already logged in, header that weenis away
if($user_ok == true){
header("location: user.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
    exit();
}
?><?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("includes/db_conx.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['p']);
// GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($e == "" || $p == ""){
echo "login_failed";
        exit();
} else {
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM transactions WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$db_id = $row[0];
$db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
if($p != $db_pass_str){
echo "login_faileda";
            exit();
} else {
// CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
$_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
    setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
// UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
$sql = "UPDATE transactions SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
echo $db_username;
   exit();
}
}
exit();
}
?>
<?php include_once("./includes/site-opener.php");?>
<title>Sign In</title>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function emptyElement(x){
_(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
var e = _("email").value;
var p = _("password").value;
if(e == "" || p == ""){
_("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
} else {
_("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
_("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signin.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
           if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
_("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
_("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
} 
           if(ajax.responseText == "login_faileda"){
_("status").innerHTML = "Next One";
_("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
} 
else {
window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
}
       }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
}
}
</script>
```

**check_login_status.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db_conx.php");
// Files that inculde this file at the very top would NOT require 
// connection to database or session_start(), be careful.
// Initialize some vars
$user_ok = false;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";
// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0){
return true;
}
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
$log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
$log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
$log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);
// Verify the user
$user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
$_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
$log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
$log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
// Verify the user
$user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
if($user_ok == true){
// Update their lastlogin datetime field
$sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
}
}
?>
```

When we get to

```
$db_id = $row[0];
$db_username = $row[1];
$db_pass_str = $row[2];
```

Does the table structure have to be in that order? As in

> [   id          |        username        |        password   ]

or can it be

> [   id          |        email        |        username          |     password   ]

How would you output the variables to see whats actually coming out?

I've included

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
var_dump($row['username']);
```

Where do I look for the output? I'm being taken to my message.php page which means its going to the user.php page, but no longer allowing for the output to display on page

### **A BREAKTHROUGH!!**

Well I was able to get it to run as I thought. The problem is I had to manually change both the email and password to get it to work. So I guess that is a start and could mean the problem isn't here after all. Maybe within the area for which the data is posted?
Any ideas or theories on what could be the issue so that I can try to tackle it.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered properly indenting your code?

Comment: Use var_dump() to show all information associated with a variable (for instance var_dump($row); ). It doesn't matter which columns you get first.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham where exactly do you place that?

Comment: @Chris var_dump($var) can be placed anywhere after $var is set. So for $row, put it after  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

Comment: I don't understand why you made such a complicated login script.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham I've updated the bottom of my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql or PHP won't magically insert a field.
My guess is that you are having unexpected data in the db.

I am not good at PHP but shouldn't one be able to do $row['username'] ?

Comment: When you said this I thought I should check the other inputs. They don't by the naked eye seem off yet they don't work. Is there something you can think of that may be causing a naked unexpected data entry?

Comment: With your breakthrough I even more believe in bad data. If you have used $row[magic-number] in other places you now know why one doesn't.